# Evil In Clear River - Two Versions?

Tags: alternate-version, evil-in-clear-river

I have seen the film Evil in Clear River, in  which a teenage student is being fed antisemitic propaganda by a school teacher. However, I seem to recall two different versions of it. In one the student is a boy in a two-parent family, but I seem to recall another in which she is the daughter of a single Mum. Is there an alternative version or am I thinking of two different films?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I started out by assuming a movie with two different principal protagonists could not possibly be the same movie - but I had no clue where to actually go from there… until I read the [reviews on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw0256830/?ref_=tt_urv)…

> Made the same year as the similar Raquel Welch movie Scandal in a Small Town, Wagner is Kate McKinnon, a chain-smoking Western prairie farmwoman who discovers the town's history teacher Peter Suvak (Randy Quaid) of her son Mark (Thomas Wilson Brown) is a neo-Nazi revisionist, who teaches about a world Jewish conspiracy.

So there you go, two movies, same year; similar plot basis, different protagonists.

**[Evil in Clear River (1988)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095121/?ref_=tt_urv)**

> Pete Suvak is a loved and respected high school teacher and mayor of a small Canadian community. After concerned mother Kate McKinnon finds out that Suvak is teaching Nazism and "Jew-bashing" to her son and others, she takes action to have him removed from the school. That doesn't help anything as he still has the community behind him. So the next step is to take Suvak to court.

**[Scandal in a Small Town (1988)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096044/)**

> Leda Beth Vincent (Raquel Welch) lives in the small town of Shiloh and works as a cocktail waitress there. She is not too well thought of, as she is nothing of a blushing virgin. But she is far from a whore and brings up her daughter Julie (Christa Denton), a high school student, as a loving responsible mother. So, when she becomes aware that Julie's very popular history teacher, Mr. George Baker (Ronny Cox), spreads anti-Semitic, racist ideas amongst his pupils…

Comment: Sometimes referred to as [*Twin Films*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films)

Comment: Welcome - though I did find it completely by accident ;))